# Why doesn't this union give me two columns?

Tags: sql-server

I want two columns in the output of the join. I only get one, the storeID. The StoreComponentID is not there.

[image: Here are the two tables, the query, and the results of the query]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: what is your desire output? two columns side by side? or one `column, null` and then `null, column`? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 3):

if you want two column you need to declare two columns

```
SELECT column1, NULL as column2 -- even when Table1 doesnt have column2
FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT NULL as column1, column2 -- even when Table2 doesnt have column1
FROM Table2
```

Now if you want some kind of merge side by side.

```
WITH idA as (
     SELECT StoreComponentID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StoreComponentID) as rn
     FROM StoreComponent
), idB as (
     SELECT StoreID
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StoreID) as rn
     FROM Store
)
SELECT idA.StoreComponentID, 
       idB.StoreID
FROM idA 
FULL JOIN idB
  ON idA.rn = idB.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a simple solution:

```
select S.storeid as sID, SC.storecomponentid as SCID from tstore as S, tstorecomponent as SC
```

[image: The results I wanted]